# gorp PreUpdate method update involuntary columns

Tags: go, orm, gorp

see below.

```
type User struct {
    Id         int64  `db:"id" json:"id"`
    Name  string `db:"name" json:"name"`
    DateCreate int64  `db:"date_create"`
    DateUpdate int64  `db:"date_update"`
}

func (u *User) PreInsert(s gorp.SqlExecutor) error {
    u.DateCreate = time.Now().UnixNano()
    u.DateUpdate = u.DateCreate
    return nil
}

func (u *User) PreUpdate(s gorp.SqlExecutor) error {
    u.DateUpdate = time.Now().UnixNano()
    return nil
}
```

I executed INSERT.

```
user := model.User{
    Name:      "John",
}

err := dbMap.Insert(&user)
```

Result of INSERT. no problem

```
1,John,1444918337049394761,1444918337049394761
```

continue, I executed UPDATE.

```
user := model.User{
    Id:        1,
    Name:      "John",
}

_, err := dbMap.Update(&user)
```

Result of UPDATE

```
1,John,0,1444918337049394900
```

Column DateCreate updated.

Of course, my expectation values are

```
1,John,1444918337049394761,1444918337049394900
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because when initializing your `user` struct, you did not explicitely set `user.DateCreate`, which effectively sets it to 0.

gorp cannot guess which fields you mean to update or not, so it updates them all.

To do what you want, you have to choose between trade-offs

1. [Get the struct from the ORM](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gorp.v1#DbMap.Get), with the field already set to the good value. That's one additional `select` query that will be executed.
2. [Execute a custom query](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gorp.v1#DbMap.Exec), losing the convenience of the ORM
3. I'm guessing you could have another `struct` type without this field. That seems messy, I do not recommend that.

Comment: Hi @HectorJ, thank you for your reply.

I understood, and I choose to use Exec() method on UPDATE.

If PreUpdate is able to exclude specific columns, very useful.